# Need some tips on how R can handle this situation

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the csv version of the Lahman 2018 database found here: http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/.

In R, I would like to identify how many extra-base hits all Mets rookies have hit in their rookie seasons by game 95. I want to find out which Met rookie hit the most extra-base hits by game 95.

I have been experimenting with dplyr functions including select, filter, and summarize.

The main thing I am uncertain about is how to get only each Mets players' doubles, triples, and homers for the first 95 games of his first season.

This code shows more of what I have done then how I think my problem can be solved -- for that I am seeking tips.

```
  library(dplyr)
  df %>% filter(teamID=='NYN') %>% 
    select(c(playerID, yearID, G, 2B, 3B, HR)) %>% 
    group_by(playerID, yearID) %>%
    summarise(xbh = sum(2B) + sum(3B)+ sum(HR)) %>%
    arrange(desc(xbh))
```

Here is how I would like the output to appear:

```
    Player  Season 2B  3B  HR  XBH
    x       1975   10   2   8   20
    y       1980   5    5   5   15
    z       2000   9    0   4   13
```

and so on.

I would like the XBH to be in descending order.

Comment: No need for `c()` in `select`.

Comment: what .csv(s) are you using? an extra-base hit is any hit that's not a single (so double, triple, homer)? what column or symbol represents a rookie?

Comment: You could easily make this reproducible by using the `Lahman` package that has all this data.

Comment: @doconnor (1) In the Lahman database I am using the Batting.csv file. (2) That's correct. (3) There is no column in the Lahman database that shows a player is a rookie. Each player's first season as a Met will be viewed as his rookie season. That is why I need a way to create a subset containing each Mets player's batting stats for his first year of play.

Comment: @axeman I know the Lahman package has all the data. I've used it. What I need to know is how to extract from it the information I presented in my second paragraph.

Comment: @Axeman Isn't the class type different when I concatenate those elements?

Comment: I just looked at batting.csv again and realized that it does not contain a game log, just season data, so that dataset can only be used to find how many extra-base hits a player had in a season. Therefore, right now, my focus needs to shift to just getting each Mets extra-base hits for his first season. Ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011847/determining-rookie-years-in-lahman-database suggests just finding rookies is not straightforward. A new question might be best.  `library(Lahman)` `batting <- merge(Master, Batting, by='playerID')` might be a start & this maybe helpful - https://baseballwithr.wordpress.com/category/lahman/